# How to make Squid log url and forward traffic without proxying?

Tags: proxy, squid, transparent-proxy

I want to use squid to listen on port 80 and log all url requests and simply forward it to original destination without changing anything. How to achieve that?

Comment: Squid *is* a proxy. I think what you're looking for is a traffic forwarder, which Squid is not. Depending on your firewall/network equipment, you can configure those to repeat/forward some or all traffic to a server that listens to the traffic and does whatever it is that you want it to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you want to do is called proxying, so maybe what you meant was to make Squid invisible and disable any caching features ?

If so, disable caching by removing all `cache_dir` and `refresh_pattern` directives from the configuration file, and add the following to make the proxy invisible to the eyes of the web servers :

```
forwarded_for transparent
via off
```

The first directive prevents Squid from altering the `X-Forwarded-For` header, so it doesn't tamper with the request in any way; the second prevents it from adding the `Via` header with its name and version, again to be as subtle and discreet as possible.